# How can I track how many times my script is run?

Tags: bash, curl, google-analytics-api

I have a simple bash script that I want to track how many times it is run. This script will be downloaded and run on other machines so I want to keep dependencies to a minimum.

I want to use curl, but I am unsure of what options there were as far as sending a POST to google analytics or something similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement Google Analytics `collect` POST request with `curl` in your script. Just add the following :

```
tracking_id="UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
category="AppCounter"
action="CountAction"
label="CountLabel"
value="1"

curl -d 'v=1&tid='"$tracking_id"'&cid=555&t=event&ec='"$category"'&ea='"$action"'&el='"$label"'&ev='"$value"'' \
     -H "User-Agent: AppSpecific" \
     "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect"
```

See the [Measurement protocol for Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference)